# How to visualise yes/no data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I don't know where this question goes, if it belongs in math, then someone should move it there.

I have a set of yes/no data (0s and 1s), what possible ways could you visualise this, apart from the normal pie charts and the like.

I want to do this in Javascript (edit: jquery would be easier), using AJAX with PHP.

Comment: Presumably you want to represent these data in aggregate? As two sums?

Answer (score 2):

Radiobuttons or Checkboxes are usually used on webpages to display Yes/No choices. Another option would be to use images like a green check mark to display a positive value and a red cross to display a negative value.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to display data. Are you looking to show it as a graph? If so, try google charts API.

Answer (score 1):

Just the binary choice with no other criteria? (time, location, etc.)

A two element bar chart, two shapes (circles?) in different sizes and colors (like a disjoint Venn diagram), or a pie chart immediately comes to mind.

Comment: I hadn't though of that, so something like a history of the data, red circle for no, green for yes,.. which you can mouseover to see which day. Thanks (now If only I could find something to do it in)

Comment: @thenoman it is good to upvote and accept an answer if you feel it answers your question.  This way others get to know the best answer and accepted solution to the problem.